# PHP File get content with regex

Tags: php, regex, file-get-contents

I'm looking to open a file in PHP with a certain regex. Here is the example. I have two files in the same folder:

20151001_Test(132489488)_test_summary.txt

20150930_Test(132489488)_test.txt

These two files are in the same folder, the number at the beginning (20151001) is changing. But I want to find the second file, just with the first's number (132489488). Something like:

```
$number = preg_replace('/20151001_Test\((.*)\)_test_summary.txt/','$1',$line);
$file = file_get_content('/.*_Test(' . $number . ')_test.txt/');
```

Someone has the answer maybe?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch the list of filenames before finding the one to use.

Something like this

```
$dir = '/your/directory/here/';
$number = preg_replace('/20151001_Test\((.*)\)_test_summary.txt/','$1',$line);
$files = scandir($dir);
$matching = preg_grep('/_Test(' . $number . ')_test.txt/');
if ($matching) {
    $file = file_get_content($matching[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It did what I wanted, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use regex arguments in `file_get_content()`; it requires a single fixed string filename.

If you want to search for files that match a pattern, then you first need to read the list of filenames from the directory. You would use [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) for this.

Then you need to search the resulting array to find the matching filenames. The PHP function for this is [`preg_grep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php). This is a regex function, you so can use your regex here.

Once you've found the matching filename using the above, *then* you can pass that filename into `file_get_contents()` to load the file.